# Input time value Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to set the value of my time input with javascript here is what I am doing

```
var div = document.createElement("DIV");
var div_id = "div_hours_" + "1";

var input_open = document.createElement("INPUT");
var today=new Date();
var h=today.getHours();
var m=today.getMinutes();
var s=today.getSeconds();
input_open.type = 'time';
input_open.name = 'time_open_input';
input_open.value = h+ ":" + m + " am";

div.appendChild(input_open);
el("body_div").appendChild(div);
```

But when I do this, I see the time input, but its value is empty?

Why isn't the value being input?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You need to

1. Define the variable numOfHours
2. Remove the line `input_open.type = 'time';` (time is not yet supported in IE)
3. Add a function for el (or you could replace it with the line - `document.getElementById("body_div").appendChild(div)` assuming your are looking to append to a div with id as body_div

---

If you are using Chrome just change your last line to (instead of doing 2. above)

```
input_open.value = h + ":" + m;
```

Comment: So 1, and 3 are done I should of included them in mode code sorry, and what do I do number 2

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime - it's not supported yet in IE. If you are using Chrome just lose the " am" in your last line and it should work.

Comment: i.e. just do `input_open.value = h + ":" + m;`

Comment: So you answer the question and mark it as duplicate too? lol

Comment: :-) it "seemed" like there were multiple problems at first, but then OP said that they were just a result of formatting the code for the question. And then I came back in a while, saw a comment (against the question I think) and went - yeah that's right, its a dupe.

Answer (score -1):

[Reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.time.html)

> value = time
>
> A string representing a time (with no timezone information).
>
> A valid partial-time as defined in [RFC 3339].
>
> Examples: 23:20:50.52 17:39:57

You may want to change the type to plain `text`.

See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Arg0n/za9hc4ay/) JSFiddle

JavaScript

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
var div_id = "div_hours_" + "1";

var input_open = document.createElement("input");
var today=new Date();
var h=today.getHours() < 10 ? "0" + today.getHours() : today.getHours();
var m=today.getMinutes() < 10 ? "0" + today.getMinutes() : today.getMinutes();
var s=today.getSeconds() < 10 ? "0" + today.getSeconds() : today.getSeconds();
input_open.type = 'text';
input_open.name = 'time_open_input';
input_open.value = h + ":" + m + " am";

div.appendChild(input_open);
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

Comment: This is more suited to a comment

Comment: Wow, that's a pretty harsh reaction, happy coding